# How to Show Dynamically Added Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create tooltips with title attribute and jQuery but can't find method to show dynamically added element.

**HTML**

```
<a href="/some-page" title="Show tooltip" class="dfn">some page</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    …
    display: none; /* I's needed for hard coded tooltips */
    …
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 980px)').matches) {
        $('.dfn').hover(
            function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var txtTitle = el.prop('title');
                el.append('<p class="tooltip">' + txtTitle + '</p>');

                //That's it. My tooltip has been created, but it has not been shown
                $(el + ' .tooltip').show('fast');
                el.data('title', el.prop('title'));
                el.removeAttr('title');
            }, function () {
                $(el + ' .tooltip').hide('fast').remove();
                el.prop('title', el.data('title'));
            }
            );
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(el + ' .tooltip')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: also... `backgrong-color`

Comment: Are you sure you mean to do `$(el + ' .tooltip');` you should do `el.find('.tooltip');`

Comment: Sorry for backgrong-color. But what's wrong with $(el + ' .tooltip')?

Comment: You probably mean el.find('.tooltip')

Comment: @user3525281 `el` is referencing `$(this)` which is a `jQuery` object, which you cannot do `+` on.

Comment: You are write. It was wrong selector.

Comment: I've rewrited code and it works now. Thanks, everybody

    $(function () {
        if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 980px)').matches) {
            $('.dfn').hover(
                function () {
                    var el = $(this);
                    var txtTitle = $(this).prop('title');
                    el.append('<p class="tooltip">' + txtTitle + '</p>');
                    el.find('.tooltip').show('fast');
                }, function () {
                    $(this).find('.tooltip').hide('fast').remove();
                }
            );
        }
    });

Comment: And final one I've wrote at morning:
$(function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 980px)').matches) {
        $('.dfn').hover(
            function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var txtTitle = el.prop('title');
                el.attr('title', '');
                el.append('<p class="tooltip">' + txtTitle + '</p>');
                el.find('.tooltip').show('fast');
            }, function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var tT = el.find('.tooltip');
                var txtTitle = tT.text();
                tT.hide('fast').remove();…

Comment: …
                el.attr('title', txtTitle);
            }
        );
    }
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others, `$(el + ' .tooltip').show('fast');` is probably wrong.

The el is an object, not a string to concat', one way is to use `el.find('.tooltip').show()`.
The other way is to use the context option: `$('.tooltip', el).show();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have correct code to find new element:

```
$('.tooltip', el).show('fast');
```

Your current one probably endup searching for something like `[object] .tooltip` or similar string depending on how JavaScript decides to convert HTML element to string.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned `el.find('.tooltip').show()` and `el.find('.tooltip').hide().remove();` solve the problem.

Also, in HandlerOut function, you el was not declared. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw4UT/)

```
$(function () {
    //if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 980px)').matches) {
        $('.dfn').hover(
            function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var txtTitle = el.prop('title');
                el.append('<p class="tooltip">' + txtTitle + '</p>');

                //That's it. My tooltip has been created, but it has not been shown
                el.find('.tooltip').show()
                el.data('title', el.prop('title'));
                el.removeAttr('title');
            }, function () {
                var el = $(this);
                el.find('.tooltip').hide().remove();
                el.prop('title', el.data('title'));
            }
            );
    //}
});
```